# What species of worm is this? Found in underwear on Ecuador coast

Tags: species-identification, entomology

[image]

My wife found this worm in her underwear this morning when she woke up.  It wasnt attached to her or anything. About 4-5 inches long. Redish in color and slightly see through, meaning you could sort of see its organs.

We are in Puerto Lopez Ecuador.

Comment: Do you think it's possible to be a parasitic worm? if yes it could be an [ascaris lumbricoides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascaris_lumbricoides) and in that case I would recommend your wife to go to a doctor because those worms can lead to bad symptoms.

Comment: Anyway whatever is the type of worm, I would consult a doctor in any case a parasit goes out of my body.

Comment: Oh for sure. We all got on parasite meds immediately.  Definitely a parasite. Was just curious what type :)

Comment: See my first comment, the worm seems to be an `ascaris lumbricoides` but  I am not specialist. It would be better if a specialist in parasitology can confirm or infirm this.